# Views and layout elements displayed conditionally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am semi-new to android development. I am getting ready to design a project that has a button that has 2 different methods when clicked (effectively a toggle). I know I can do this by implementing OnClickListener myself, but I was wondering if there was a way to make 2 different buttons in the layout xml and then conditionally show one or the other appropriately. Also if this is possible, is it generally a good practice, or is there a better way to have a button perform two different methods? Is it easier overall to just go ahead and implement OnClickListener?

Thanks

(I currently don't have any code to show at the moment, but if my question is vague I'll be happy to elaborate more if necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about it and if the only difference between the buttons is what they do when clicked, you should use only one button and either:

1. Use an if/else in the `onClick()` method or click listener to control the behavior, OR
2. Use `button.setOnClickListener()` to change the listener when you want to change the behavior

However if the buttons are significantly different (e.g. different location ...etc), use my other answer.

Comment: I think this is more of what I'm looking for because my overall goal is to have a single button (or effectively a single button) that does 2 different things alternatively on each click.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it very easy. Put both buttons in your layout XML, and add the attribute `android:visibility=GONE` to one of them. In your Java code you can change the visibility of your buttons with `button.setView(View.VISIBLE)` and `button.setView(View.GONE)`. (Don't use button.setView(View.INVISIBLE) because the button will be invisible but still take up space in the View).

Comment: Would I be able to have them sit on top of each other in the layout? I was unaware of the visibility attribute, thanks for that.

Comment: What do you mean by sit on top of each other? Just insert the <button> tags consecutively in the XML file, with the same layout attributes and you should be ok as long as you make sure only one is visible at a time. BTW I've been thinking about your problem as I'm posting another answer below...